# How to sort items in a list by a comma delimited number and remove the number afterwards in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have text in a list like this:

```
something , 3
something else , 1
something this , 2
```

And this code correctly sorts the list by the number to the right of the comma:

```
data_list= sorted(data_list, key=lambda line: int(line.rsplit(' ,', 1)[1]))
```

After the sort, how can I remove the comma delimited numbers, leaving just the part before the comma?

I tried this and it removes the numbers, but the sorting is lost. Somehow this changes the order.

```
data_list= [sen.split(' ,')[0] for sen in data_list]
```

Comment: I don't see why it would. Please show exact code you use and exact answer. [mcve]

Comment: Your above code works for me. Can't reproduce.

Comment: Yeah, works for me too. Tested on Python 2.7.12. This is not a reproducible issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than sort while in string form and parse afterwards, it would be better to parse first, then sort.

```
>>> import csv
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> text = ['something , 3', 'something else , 1', 'something this , 2']
>>> list(map(itemgetter(0), sorted(csv.reader(text), key=itemgetter(1))))
['something else ', 'something this ', 'something ']
```

Here are the steps explained:

```
# First parse the commas into separate fields
csv.reader(text)    
 \-->  [['something ', ' 3'], ['something else ', ' 1'], ['something this ', ' 2']]

# Then sort using the second field as the key
sorted(_, key=itemgetter(1))
 \--> [['something else ', ' 1'], ['something this ', ' 2'], ['something ', ' 3']]

# The extract just the field
list(map(itemgetter(0), _))
 \--> ['something else ', 'something this ', 'something ']
```

As **@donkopotamus** mentioned, you can replace the key-function with `key=lambda x: int(x[1])` to sort numerically rather than alphabetically.

Comment: Or `..., key=lambda x: int(x[1])` to handle multi digit numbers

Comment: @donkopotamus  Yes, that would be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
data_list = ['something , 3',
'something else , 1',
'something this , 2']

data_list= [i.split(',')[0] for i in sorted(data_list, key=lambda line: int(line.split(',')[1]))]
```

results in

```
['something else ', 'something this ', 'something ']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
[x.strip() for x, y in sorted([x.split(",") for x in data], 
                              key=lambda row: int(row[1]))]
```

Gives:

```
['something else', 'something this', 'something']
```

Here we:

- split each row, then
- sort the data according to the second item *as an integer*, then
- take the first items (stripping them for whitespace)